# How to keep variable in scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I have an associative array of objects that I want to extend with a number of functions.
`myCtrls //Array of objects`

I do this with the following loop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (ctrlName in fieldCtrls){
        var ctrl = fieldCtrls[ctrlName];

        ctrl.Initialize = function(){
            //Do some stuff
            ctrl.someProperty = "newValue";
        }
        ctrl.Validate= function(){
            //Do some more stuff
            ctrl.someProperty = "validation ok";
        }
}
```

Later on, I execute a function like this. However the variable 'ctrl' now always points to the last object in 'fieldCtrls'. How can I make the variable 'ctrl' work inside 'initialize()' and 'Validate()'?

```
fieldCtrls['id'].Validate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope would change to the calling object - `fieldCtrls['id']`. You should therefore be able to use `this` to access internal properties.

```
ctrl.Validate= function(){
  //Do some more stuff
  this.someProperty = "validation ok";
}
```

Comment: Ah, why didnt I thick of that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://calculist.blogspot.com/2005/12/gotcha-gotcha.html) describes the problem you're seeing. The `var ctrl` declaration is actually interpreted as being function-local, not local to the loop.

You can work around this by writing something like this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (ctrlName in fieldCtrls){
        function(ctrl) { // create a new anonymous function ...
            ctrl.Initialize = function(){
                //Do some stuff
                ctrl.someProperty = "newValue";
            }
            ctrl.Validate= function(){
                //Do some more stuff
                ctrl.someProperty = "validation ok";
            }
        }(fieldCtrls[ctrlName]); // ... and call the function right away
    }
}
```

This forces a new scope for `ctrl` for each loop iteration, so each function captures a different variable, instead of the same one each time.

(N.B. Untested, and I'm not a JavaScript guru. This problem, however, plagues most scripting languages with closure support.)

Comment: Thank you! You managed to explain closures to me! Ive read alot about it but hadnt still grasped it.

Comment: Wow, and I didn't even really try. I figured I'd just post this, even though Ivar's solution is better in this particular case, but this is more generally applicable.